# Spring MVC 3.2 Backbone.js Post

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, backbone.js

I'm working on a Google App engine web application with Backbone.js and Spring mvc. I have the following backbone.js code:

```
       var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
               "title": "",
               "postTxt": ""
            }
        });

        var PostCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
              url: '/createUserPost',
              model: PostModel
        });

        var postcollection = new PostCollection();


      function createPost() {


           var postview = new PostView();
           postcollection.create({ title: $('#title').val(), postTxt:   $('#postTxt').val() });

           title: $('#title').val('');
           post: $('#postTxt').val('');

       }
```

Spring mvc 3.2 code on the backend:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/createUserPost", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody UserPosts createUserPost(   @ModelAttribute(value="post")  UserPosts post,
```

@CookieValue(value = "sessionId", defaultValue = "null") String sessionId) {

```
    //my custom method to get user name by querying the datastore
    String author = getAuthorFromSessionId(sessionId);              

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    try {


        post.setAuthor(author);
        pm.makePersistent(post);

    }
    finally {

        pm.close();

    }



    return post;
}
```

When post button is clicked, The text is added to the HTML correctly and POST request is made to the server and the status code is 200 OK. 
Spring controller is not able to read the request parameters. Alternatively, I tried using HttpServletRequest and request.getParameter("title") without autobinding, but value returned was still null.
Data sent in the request:

```
             {title: "kdkldklfd", postTxt: "kkfdlksffkl"}
```

Response received:

```
             {"title":null,"author":"admin","postTxt":null}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createUserPost", method=RequestMethod.POST, 
consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody UserPosts createUserPost(@RequestBody  UserPosts post) {
```

The @RequestBody annotation should be used in place of  @ModelAttribute  to read the Request parameters.

Comment: But, @ModelAttribute(value="post")  UserPosts post  is able to autobind all request parameters. when i use a plain jquery                   $.ajax({  type: "POST", url: '/createpost', data: $('#myform').serialize() })